# iOS Camera not working at the time of phone call

Tags: ios, camera

I am using  [LLSimpleCamera example](https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera) in one of my project. I got stuck in a condition and can't move forward. The scenario is, suppose when I am using the api to take snap, and at that time some one calls me, then the camera screen gets black . Then it shows an error in the log :

> LLSimpleCameraExample[332:96074] 18:54:22.911 ERROR:
>   [AVAudioSession Notify Thread] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:49:
>   ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port iPhone
>   Microphone (type: MicrophoneBuiltIn)

After disconnecting the call , the camera screen works perfectly.

Can you please help me to solve the problem?